# Unmarshalling JSON data with nested arrays and objects into Go struct

Tags: arrays, json, go, youtube, unmarshalling

I am unmarshalling Youtube json response into Go struct by using the data received from Youtube API as follows:-

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/5xHRkUxevhiDF1huCnKw2ybduyo\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CBQQAA",
 "regionCode": "TH",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 36,
  "resultsPerPage": 20
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/aMbszoNudZchce3BIjZC_YemugE\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "fvh6CQ7FxZE"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-07-16T14:42:36.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCuX4iswo8acMxDNcbrceRYQ",
    "title": "Japan อร่อยสุดๆ:การประชันของ 2 สาวกับราเมงดังจากโอซาก้า#ramen",
    "description": "Ramen Kio ราเมนชื่อดังของโอซาก้าอัดแน่นด้วยเนื้อหมูชาชูแบบเต็มๆเส้นเหนีย...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fvh6CQ7FxZE/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fvh6CQ7FxZE/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fvh6CQ7FxZE/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Japan aroi sudsud TV",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

To do so, I have created a struct for this in Go

```
type YoutubeData struct {
    Kind          string `json:"kind"`
    Etag          string `json:"etag"`
    NextPageToken string `json:"nextPageToken"`
    RegionCode    string `json:"regionCode"`
    PageInfo      struct {
        TotalResults   string `json:"totalResults"`
        ResultsPerPage string `json:"resultsPerPage"`
    } `json:"pageInfo"`
    Items []struct {
        Kind string `json:"kind"`
        Etag string `json:"etag"`
        Id   struct {
            Kind    string `json:"kind"`
            VideoId string `json:"videoId"`
        } `json:"id"`
        Snippet struct {
            PublishedAt string `json:"publishedAt"`
            ChannelId   string `json:"channelId"`
            Title       string `json:"title"`
            Description string `json:"description"`
            Thumbnails  struct {
                Default struct {
                    Url    string `json:"url"`
                    Width  string `json:"width"`
                    Height string `json:"height"`
                } `json:"default"`
                Medium struct {
                    Url    string `json:"url"`
                    Width  string `json:"width"`
                    Height string `json:"height"`
                } `json:"medium"`
                High struct {
                    Url    string `json:"url"`
                    Width  string `json:"width"`
                    Height string `json:"height"`
                } `json:"high"`
            } `json:"thumbnails"`
            ChannelTitle         string `json:"channelTitle"`
            LiveBroadcastContent string `json:"liveBroadcastContent"`
        } `json:"snippet"`
    } `json:"items"`
}
```

I unmarshaled it by using this method

```
youtubeData := YoutubeData{}

if json.Unmarshal(b, &youtubeData); err != nil {

} else {

}
```

In which b is the byte data received from Youtube API. I successfully got all data in the byte object as I printed it out to my console, however, once I unmarshaled it and tried to output it on the template by using {{.}}, I received

```
{youtube#searchListResponse "5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/JwGY0TWwWswjZ9LOvemaF5yxsMo" CBQQAA TH { } []}
```

All data are unmarshaled except for the data in json object and array which are *pageInfo* and *items*. There are simply blank. I believe I exported them all correctly. Are there some additional steps to get the data into slice or struct nested inside another struct in Go when it comes to json unmarshalling?

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out that when I use auto generated json to Go from

https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Now it works perfectly. I will never manually craft it by hand ever again.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the json data contains numbers for `TotalResults` and `ResultsPerPage`. You can try decoding these as follows:

```
PageInfo      struct {
    TotalResults   json.Number `json:"totalResults"`
    ResultsPerPage json.Number `json:"resultsPerPage"`
} `json:"pageInfo"`
```

Once you have the unmarshalled struct, you can get the number as:

```
totalResults, _ := youtubeData.PageInfo.TotalResults.Int64()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your struct must have fields with the same data types JSON body has, in your JSON body `totalResults` and `resultsPerPage` are integers, so:

```
PageInfo      struct {
    TotalResults   int `json:"totalResults"`
    ResultsPerPage int `json:"resultsPerPage"`
} `json:"pageInfo"`
```